# Как реализовать корзину на Vue JS и Laravel, если не авторизованный пользователь

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router, laravel-5.8

Пишу приложение на Vue и Laravel, но теперь столкнулся с такой проблемой.
У меня приходит пользователь, и чтобы его не реализовывать для заказа создаю session() с ключом.

Но после добавления товара этот ключ(сессия) постоянно приходит пустая и при каждом новом заказе создаётся новый ключ

Код на BackEnd -

```
public function AddProductToCart($id, Request $request){
    $basketId = $request->session()->get('basketId');

    if (is_null($basketId)){
        $basketId = session(['basketId']);
        $basket = Basket::create();
        session(['basketId'=> $basket->id]);
    } else {
        $basket = Basket::find($basketId);
    }

    $basket->products()->attach($id);
    dump($basket->products);
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
    $data = $request->session()->get('basketId');
    dd($product, $basketId, $data);
}
```

На Vue js такой код -

```
addToCart(product){
            this.productToCart = product;
            console.log(this.productToCart);
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Добавить товар',
                text: this.productToCart.title+ " в корзину?",
                icon: 'question',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                confirmButtonText: 'Да, добавить',
                cancelButtonText: 'Отмена'
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.isConfirmed) {
                    //Send request to the server
                    this.form.post('products/add/'+product.id).then(()=>{

                        console.log(result.isConfirmed);
                        Swal.fire(
                            'Успешно!',
                            'Продукт'+this.productToCart.title+'был добавлен',
                            'success'
                        );
                    }).catch(() => {
                        Swal.fire({
                            title: 'Error!',
                            text: 'Somthing went wrong',
                            icon: 'error',
                            confirmButtonText: 'Cool'
                        })
                    });
                } //result finish
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

`dd()` это «dump and die» и "Под капотом" вызывает `die();` которая в свою очередь завершает работу фреймворка и не позволяет правильно сохранить данные сессии. Хорошей практикой для отладки сессии является иcпользование `dump();` или `var_dump();`